# Referencing equations in Lyx

Tags: cross-referencing, lyx

In LyX, the equation label appearing next to a formula is, for example, `(2.6,eq:Monotone)`. Here, `eq:Monotone` is the equation label set and (2.6) is the equation number as in the document.

To reference this equation, the Cross-reference-dialog offers selecting `eq:Monotone`, but not (2.6).

Is there a way to select (2.6) to reference this equation?

Comment: As you can see, this place works best when posting code, which can be used right a way and shows your problem. Thank you